# Which one is more idiomatic/preferred in Scala: Map(<stuff>: _*) or <stuff>.toMap?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

These seem to be effectively equivalent:

```
scala> ("asd" zip "zxc").toMap
res62: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Char] = Map(a -> z, s -> x, d -> c)

scala> Map(("asd" zip "zxc"): _*)
res63: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Char] = Map(a -> z, s -> x, d -> c)
```

However, what are the real life differences? Which one is more idiomatic? Will runtime performance be any different?

I'm sure the same/a similar question can probably be asked about other, analogous pairs of constructs, so feel free to give a more general/abstract answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a real difference between the two because of *where* these methods are defined:

- the `apply` *constructor* is defined in the *target* collection's companion:

  ```
  object Coll {
    def apply[T](els: T*): Coll[T] = ???
  }
  ```

  This means it has absolutely no information about the input other than a `Seq` of elements, so it just traverses that sequence and builds a `Coll`.
- on the other hand,`toSeq`, `toArray`, ... are defined in the *source* collection, meaning they have all that extra information about its internals.

Usually, you can count on the `toXXX` methods to short-circuit when needed, or to return some specialized collection that makes sense.

As a silly example, consider:

```
List(1,2,3).toSeq // toSeq returns `this`, there is no overhead
// vs.
Seq(List(1,2,3): _*) // this will copy that list into a new one...
```

This gets worse is you replace that list with `Stream.continually(1)`...

Comment: Do mutable collections also short-circuit like this?

Comment: `toIterable` and `toTraversable` will short-circuit even for mutable collections, and `toSeq` might too depending on the collection, but `toMap`, `toSet`, etc. always return *immutable* collections, so there will be a conversion.

Comment: That sounds to me like a potential source for bugs—wouldn't the programmer intuitively assume `to*` returns a new collection that can be modified without problems? Or is this just something one needs to know beforehand and that's it?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally prefer the first variant as it's more clear and readable. There are no actual difference between the two in performance or other characteristics. In the first case you make an index seq and then convert it to map in the second you use this seq extractor sintax `:_*` And this is the best part of Scala. Like Prof. Odersky told many many many, it was a part of Scala design to give make design solutions for different problems. So in this case, you can choose any. But as i told you the first one is more clear and understandable, leave hard-core symbol programming to `Scalaz` =)

Comment: In that case, why would Scalaz prefer `Map(<stuff>: _*)` over `<stuff>.toMap`? :) To be more hard-core?

Comment: @ErikAllik It's really depends on the case where you are using it. It all comes to the style it one case you are calling a method on a IndexedSeq, like in traditional OO, and in the seconds case you are passing in an arg creating some data with hidden `apply` like in FP. I can't answer for Scalaz guys, but i think the seconds way looks more functional than the method call

Comment: So it all just boils down to the looks? Or maybe there are also practical differences?